# Echo javascript without change the code

Tags: php

hello guys i need to echo the javascript code bellow but i don't know to escape single quotes.
And if i change the single quotes and replace it with double quotes will i have any problem with this change?

```
(function() {
    var as = document.createElement('script');
    as.type = 'text/javascript';
    as.async = true;
    as.src = "https://bf1cthsdr.cloudfront.net/atrk.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s);
})();
```

i need to do an echo like this:

```
echo '(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();';
```

Comment: You should have already known this stuff. I would use a separate page for JavaScript anyways, like `<script type='text/javascript' src='yourJS.php'></script>`. That way the output will still cache into your Client's Browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid needing to escape quotes in a string literal, use [PHP's Heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
echo <<<END
(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://bf1cthsdr.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();
END;
```

If you're willing to take the time to escape special characters, you'll need to use a `\` character to escape `'` characters within your JavaScript:

```
echo '(function() { var as = document.createElement(\'script\');...etc...';
//                                                  ^       ^
```

A good IDE will syntax highlight your PHP, so it should be easier to see when text is incorrectly escaped.

A better way to organize your code would be to move the JS to a separate file:

<sub>script.js</sub>

```
(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://bf1cthsdr.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();
```

<sub>script.php</sub>

```
...other code...
include('script.js');
...more code...
```

The reason this is better is because you'll be able to modify the JS code separately from your PHP in an editor that allows you to syntax highlight your JS.

Answer (score 2):

To escape a `'` you need to place a `\` in front of it. Since your string is wrapped with single quotes, every single quote inside it will need to look like this `\'`.

The same would be true if your string was wrapped with double quotes. You would need to escape all double quotes inside the string with `\"`.

```
echo '(function() { var as = document.createElement(\'script\'); as.type = \'text/javascript\'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lot's of quotes to put inside quotes then do something like:

```
echo "(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = 'https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();";
```

You cannot put the same type of quotes inside one another, because PHP looks for the next matching quote that is not escaped with `\`.

I usually put single inside double quotes to allow for PHP variable insertion and because, if there are a lot of quotes, it saves me form hitting the shift key, which typing double quotes requires.